# F# efficient way to convert Map into Dict (and vice versa)

Tags: dictionary, f#

I didn't find any native function to do the conversion from Dict into Map and viceversa. (Something like `Map.ofDict` or `Dict.ofMap`.)
Main reason being maps are immutable while dictionaries are not.

Have I missed something?

Comment: And by `Dict` you mean `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There isn't a convenient function to go from dictionary to map but there is a built in `dict` function which converts from a sequence of tuples to an `IDictionary<'a,'b>`, see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353774.aspx.

The simplest way I know to do the dictionary to map conversion is:

```
let dictToMap (dic : System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<_,_>) = 
    dic 
    |> Seq.map (|KeyValue|)  
    |> Map.ofSeq
```

The reverse is easy with the dict function:

```
let mapToDict map =
    map 
    |> Map.toSeq
    |> dict
```

Note that the above function returns an `IDictionary`, the implementation of which is both internal to the FSharp.Core library and not mutable.

If you want to get to a standard .NET mutable dictionary, you use the constructor which accepts an `IDictionary`, `Map` implements `IDictionary` so this step is very straightforward.

```
let mapToMutDict map =
    map :> System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<_,_>
    |> System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary
```

Comment: Thanks. in terms of performance, are those efficient or is there something to watch out for ?

Comment: @FaguiCurtain I missed an obvious alternative to go straight to `Dictionary`, answer updated :) I think all of these should be reasonably efficient, yes.

Comment: It can be shortened to `Seq.map (|KeyValue|) >> Map.ofSeq`.

Comment: @Daniel Good call on the `(|KeyValue|)` expression, have updated that part in my answer.  I purposefully didn't omit the arg with composition though because it would have meant adding a lot of explicit type annotations to keep it generic.  For a compositional solution, I prefer this: `Map.ofSeq << Seq.map (|KeyValue|) <| dic`.